# Geo-Replication in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a App service hosted in Windows Azure in a region. When there are some issues with Azure servers in the hosted region, the app service goes down and the users are unable to see the website.

I would like to know if there is a way to geo-replicate the app service so that if the servers are down in 1 region, the website should automatically redirect it to a different server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can geo-replicate your app service by using [`Azure Traffic Manager`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/) service, which allows you to control the distribution of user traffic to your service endpoints running in different datacenters around the world.

As of today, Azure Traffic Manager provides 3 ways for routing the traffic: [`Priority`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-routing-methods/#priority-traffic-routing-method), [`Weighted`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-routing-methods/#weighted-traffic-routing-method) and [`Performance`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-routing-methods/#performance-traffic-routing-method). For what you're looking to accomplish, I believe you would want to choose `Priority` routing method.

To learn more about how you can make use of this service to make your app service highly available, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-geo-distributed-scale/.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old entry but I thought I'd chime in after working with Azure for a few years.

If your statement "When there are some issues with Azure servers in the hosted region" is referring to transient outages, what you might be experiencing is your App Service Plan instance transitioning.  Microsoft regularly moves ASP instances to new machines for reasons that make sense to them. Likely this is to load balance hardware or apply patches to the underlying VMs that host app services.

It has been my experience that when the ASP instances are moved, the new ASP instance needs time to warmup the app services hosted on it.  If your ASP is configured with only 1 instance, your app service will be unreachable during this time.

If on the other hand, you configure your ASP with a minimum of 2 instances, Microsoft will synchronize the moving of the instances so that at least 1 remains up and available while the other is being moved.

Of course running a multi instance ASP requires your application to either be stateless or built using a session provider other than the default .Net "In Memory" session provider. CosmosDB for instance.